# Get all WWI records from Auckland Museum Online Cenotaph API as one .json, then combine and transform to .csv

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I'm trying to write a Python script that will extract as one large .json file the (as of this writing) 105,445 WWI serviceperson records from [api.aucklandmuseum.com](https://api.aucklandmuseum.com/#cenotaph), as shown in [this SPARQL query](http://yasgui.org/short/IHUyn87lO).

So far I have this code:

```py
import requests
import json

url = "http://api.aucklandmuseum.com/search/cenotaph/_search"

numfrom = 0
i = 0

while numfrom <= 105500:
    print("From:", numfrom)

    payload = "{\"sort\":[{\"dc_identifier\":{\"order\":\"asc\"}}],\"from\":"
    payload += (str(numfrom))
    payload += ",\"size\":500,\"query\":{\"match\":{\"am_war\":\"World War I, 1914-1918\"}}}"
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

    outputjson = response.text

    outfilename =  "OC"
    outfilename += str(i)
    outfilename += ".json"

    print("Start of",outfilename,":\n",outputjson[:175]) # just first 175 chars

    with open(outfilename, mode = 'w+') as outfile:
        json.dump(outputjson, outfile)

    i += 1
    numfrom += 500
```

This gets 500 records at a time and dumps them to files, printing to the console the head of each file to test that the results are as expected.

I need to combine all this JSON into one big file, but several issues arise:

The JSON output is structured like this:

```json
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 2,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 104767,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "cenotaph-2019-06-18",
                "_type": "am:MilitaryPerson",
                "_id": "http://api.aucklandmuseum.com/id/person/C53694",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "am_medicalInformation": [
                        {
                            "am_medical": [
                                "Other/WWI"
                            ],
                            "am_record_score": [
                                "0"
                            ],
                            "am_notes": [
                                "Nature of Injury: G.S.W. right foot\nPension: 10/-\nPercent of disability: [Not stated]\nSource: New Zealand. Army (1920). List of the names of all ex-members of the New Zealand Expeditionary Force, suffering permanent disability from 20% to 100%"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
[…]
```

How can I write code (separately to the above would be fine) to **combine all JSON output** (while retaining the `_id` of each record, along with its `_source` data) **then "flatten" that data and transform it into a .csv?**

I hope the above is clear.

Thank you
Hugh

p.s.: the server is running [ElasticSearch v1.5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/index.html).

Comment: "how can I generate files named …a1, …b1, etc"...why use letters at all? Why not just number them?

Comment: For the rest, it would help greatly if you show the structure of the CSV expecting, and how the columns map to the items in the JSON. Because going from a nested structure to a flat one, it's not always obvious what the mapping is going to be.

Comment: Thanks; I will just number them. The CSV should replicate the structure of the JSON, which in some cases can be multiple nested keys with muliple values. Any script would need to traverse the JSON to find all possible column names. A complex request, I realise.

Comment: "The CSV should replicate the structure of the JSON, which in some cases can be multiple nested keys with muliple values"...makes no sense at all, because CSV is a flat-file structure and can't represent nested structures directly. e.g. what will you do with repeated items within a parent item? That's why we need a mapping / set of rules for exactly what to do. Maybe if you write that, the implementation itself will become a bit clearer to you.